generalized cumulant generating function?
The generalized moment generating function (MGF) is defined (at least in some of the signal processing literature) by
\begin{equation}
M_X^{(r)}(t) \doteq {\mathbb E}(X^r\exp{(tX)}.
\end{equation}
The usual MGF is then simply $M_X(t) \equiv M_X^{(0)}(t)$.
Now, I can see the benefit of the generalized MGF. Then, I can get the $r$th raw moment simply by using the generalized MGF with $r$, and there is no need for any differentiation.
Now, the traditional cumulant generating function (CGF) is given by $K_X(t)\doteq \log M_X(t)$. Then differentiating $K_X(t)$  with respect to $t$ $r$ times and evaluating at $t=0$ gives me the $r$th cumulant $\kappa_r$.
My question is: is there a generalized CGF that can help me avoid the repeated differentiation of the CGF to get higher order cumulants? Something like, for instance, $\log M_X^{(r)}(t)$?
Thank you for any insights!
